# Granting Select Rights to a Stored Procedure in SQL Server 2000

Tags: sql-server

I want to give a user access to a stored procedure, but not to all the objects in the database the stored procedure needs to use.

What is the best way to give rights to the stored procedure to enable it to work, but only grant execute access to the user to run it.

I am using sql server 2000 sp4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa214299.aspx)

> Users can be granted permission to
>   execute a stored procedure even if
>   they do not have permission to execute
>   the procedure's statements directly

Answer (score 2):

try

exec grant exec ON 'myprocname' TO 'myusername'